# Infering the type of the arguments in method for aspectj

Tags: java, reflection, guava, aspectj, aop

In AOP(using Aspectj) to intercept a method call and acess its parameters we can use

```
Object[] args=joinPoint.getArgs();
```

But does the JoinPoint class gives us any feature to infer the type of the parameters? For instance:

```
public void setApples(List<Apple>){..}
```

All I get is an `Object` instance. Is there some way to infer the type of that parameter using the `joinpoint` properties or reflection or `Guava TypeToken`?

Comment: generics are compile time only. you can check the type in runtime using instanceOf

Answer (score 1):

If the argument is not null, you can check the type using `instanceof` as @Babur writes in his comment, or inspect its `Class` when it's not null:

```
Object[] args = joinPoints.getArgs();
if (args[0] instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("First arg is a String of length " + ((String) args[0]).length());
}
if (args[1] == null) {
    System.out.println("Second arg is null");
} else {
    System.out.println("Second arg is a " + args[1].getClass());
}
```

If you really need to analyze the parameters of the method, you can cast [`jointPoint.getSignature()`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/index.html?org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html) to a [`MethodSignature`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/index.html?org/aspectj/lang/reflect/MemberSignature.html) to access the [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/reflect/Method.html):

```
if (joinPoint.getSignature() instanceof MethodSignature) {
    Method method = ((MethodSignature) jointPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
    System.out.println("Method parameters: " + Arrays.toString(method.getParameterTypes()));
}
```